# How do I load this kind of data into Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have some data in the following format:

strides=91 timestamp=1406058867253 distance=3146 heartbeatnumber=203 speed=0 heartrate=92
strides=91 timestamp=1406058867995 distance=3146 heartbeatnumber=204 speed=0 heartrate=92
strides=91 timestamp=1406058869106 distance=3146 heartbeatnumber=206 speed=0 heartrate=92
strides=91 timestamp=1406058870216 distance=3146 heartbeatnumber=207 speed=0 heartrate=92

What's the easiest way of loading them into Matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a text file, for example data.txt, you can do the following:

First create a file id so you can reference to your text file from within matlab:

```
FID = fopen('data.txt')
```

Now you can formulate a format specifier as described at http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec

For your case this is:

```
formatSpec = 'strides=%d timestamp=%d distance=%d heartbeatnumber=%d speed=%f heartrate=%d'
```

In which `%d` represents an integer (a whole number) and `%f` a floating point number (a decimal number so to speak). Now you can import the text in MatLab by using the function textscan(), documentation also found in the link above, and store the read data in C.

```
C = textscan(FID,formatSpec)
```

The result will be a cell array in which each cell represents a column. So in this case:

```
C{1} % Vector containing strides
C{2} % Vector containing timestamp
C{3} % Vector containing distance
C{4} % Vector containing heartbeatnumber
C{5} % Vector containing speed
C{6} % Vector containing heartrate
```

At the end close the file again:

```
fclose(FID)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is space or tab delimited (looks like it to me) then you could use:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tdfread.html

The data would be read into Matlab as a scalar structure, though you would have to think carefully about how you want that organized based on how that text file looks (i.e. is each line a person? or a point in time? this isn't really clear to me)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the Home tab inside of MATLAB and click on the Import Data Button at the top of the screen. You can then chose the file where that information is stored and chose in what way you want to import the data or to generate a script or function for importing the data. It is a very useful tool and I hope it works for you! :)